# Difference between $\dbinom{n}{2}$ and $\dbinom{n}{1}\dbinom{n-1}{1}$

Tags: combinatorics

I was thinking about $\dbinom{n}{2}$ as a process with 2 steps:
-First step: Select one element from a set with $n$ elements $\dbinom{n}{1}$
-Second step: Select one more element from a set with $n-1$ elements $\dbinom{n-1}{1}$
Result: $\dbinom{n}{1}\dbinom{n-1}{1}$

But this is not equal to $\dbinom{n}{2}$. So what's the difference?

Comment: In the case of $\binom{n}{1}\binom{n-1}{1}$ the *order* that you picked the elements mattered.  In the case of $\binom{n}{2}$ the order doesn't matter.  If you want to correct your count, realize that every outcome $\{a,b\}$ is counted exactly twice in your count.  Once as $(a,b)$ and again as $(b,a)$.  Dividing by two fixes the count.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is that $\binom{n}2$ is the number of *unordered* pairs of distinct elements of the set, while $\binom{n}1\binom{n-1}1$ is the number of *ordered* pairs. Say the set is $\{1,\ldots,n\}$. The unordered two-element set $\{1,2\}$ is the same whether you pick the $1$ first and then the $2$, or the $2$ first and then the $1$. However, the ordered pairs $\langle 1,2\rangle$ and $\langle 2,1\rangle$ are *not* the same.

You would be better off thinking of $\binom{n}2$ as counting the outcomes of a single operation, that of picking $2$ elements at the same time, so that there is not even in principle a first and a second element.